# Ferry prices in Åland islands

Tags: ferries, sweden, finland, aland

What is the cheapest way to travel from Sweden to Finland and vice versa with ferries through Åland islands?

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few options, all spelled out on Wikivoyage's [Åland page](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/%C3%85land#Get_in).

Generally, for travel between Finland and Sweden, **buying cheap return cruises** is the cheapest option.  So your best bet is likely to buy a return cruise from Stockholm to Turku, get off in Mariehamn on the way in, buy a separate Mariehamn-Turku ticket and then use the return leg of the cruise to get back from Turku to Stockholm.  And you'll want Turku instead of Helsinki, since that way the stop at Mariehamn is during the day, not in the middle of the night.  Cruise tickets will only work for a fairly quick trip though, since cruises are usually limited to a couple of days at the destination.

Unlike airlines, where getting off mid-journey will invalidate the rest of your flights, there is generally no "ticket control" of any kind when leaving the ferry, so the ferry company likely won't even realize you've done this.  However, I've never actually tried this and am not intimately familiar with how disembarkation at Mariehamn works, so YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

Viking Line offers route trips with return trip to a different port. From their website you can book trip from Stockholm to Mariehamn and from Mariehamn to Turku. You have option to choose how many days you want to be in Mariehamn. At least two nights might be a good idea so you get a full day in Mariehamn.

Booking a cabin is not required since you are traveling at daytime. Prices seems to be about 15 to 18€ per one leg. So about 30 to 40€ in total. Then you need one way ticket from Turku to Stockholm. It will cost about 30€ if you choose morning departure. Evening departure is a bit more expensive as you have to book a cabin.

Tallink Silja is currently not cruising from Stockholm. One option would be to take Tallink Silja for the part from Mariehamn to Turku. Combine this with morning departure from Turku and you will get three different ships for your trip!

For the return to Stockholm you can also book overnight cruise from Helsinki. It’s a bit more expensive and it takes a bit longer time than from Turku.